# Environment-Specific Configuration of Spring+Hibernate application

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm struggling to configure my Spring application using different .properties files for hibernate. My plan was to create an maven property that would reflect which environment I want to choose, selected via profile. And then on mine hibernate.cfg.xml would load the properties variables.

File: hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
.... <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</property>  ...
```

File: persistence-dev.properties:

```
... hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create ...
```

File: spring-context.xml:

```
... <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*persistence-${envTarget}.properties" /> ...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hibernate.cfg.xml` is not managed by Spring.

Trying to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (or it's replacement `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`) in order to filter it is useless.

What you can do is use Maven resource filtering support:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>dev</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>validate</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

You can also use it in conjunction with Spring profiles support (assuming you are willing to pass Spring profile name to Maven during build time, not only using runtime, which you will do anyway if you run Spring profiles related tests from Maven):

```
    <profile>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>dev</hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>
        </properties>
   </profile>
   ...
```

Comment: Now, is it possible to change the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property just for one specific class?

Comment: Also, is it possible to share properties between profiles?

Comment: If you want to share properties between the two profiles, you better declare them in the `properties` section of the pom file. I don't understand what you mean by change a property for a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it in the below way:

Kept common properties to all environment in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file as below.

```
 <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>

            <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>

            <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

          <!-- DB mapping if any -->    
            <mapping class='classname'></mapping>


        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Add the properties in `HibernateUtil.java` class which changes at run-time as per environment(url, username,password, dialect). You can keep these property values in different environment files like local.properties, dev.properties and load them at run-time.

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.FileBasedConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters;
import org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibernateUtil {

    static private org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration loadTestData;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateUtil(){
         loadTestData = loadPropertiesFile("local");
    }

    static {
        try {

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", loadTestData.getString("connection.url"));
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", loadTestData.getString("connection.username"));
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", loadTestData.getString("connection.password"));
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            cfg.configure();

            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed" + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration loadPropertiesFile(String filename) {
        Parameters params = new Parameters();
        FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
                new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                        .configure(params.properties()
                                .setFileName(filename + ".properties"));
        try {
            org.apache.commons.configuration2.Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
            return config;
        } catch (ConfigurationException cex) {
            // loading of the configuration file failed
            System.out.println(filename + " is not loaded" + cex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Below is `local.properties` file which is placed in resources folder

```
#hibernate properties
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rivigo
connection.username=root
connection.password=root
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between Spring profiles use `resources/logback-spring.xml` instead of `logabck.xml` and add tags:

```
</configuration>
  <springProfile name="prod">
    ...
  </springProfile>
  <springProfile name="dev,qa,stg">
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG"/>
    <!-- Hibernate SQL statements-->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="ALL"/>
    <!-- SQL queries-->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
    <!-- SQL query parameters:-->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE" />
  </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your environment during startup, you can have multiple `hibernate.cfg.xml` files in your resource directory like so:

```
resources/
 - hibernate.cfg.Development.xml
 - hibernate.cfg.Production.xml
```

Then in your code, you load the environment specific hibernate file:

**Java**

```
Environment environment = Environment.Development;
StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(String.format("hibernate.cfg.%s.xml", environment.toString())).build();
MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(registry);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

**Scala**

```
val environment: Environment = Environment.Development
val registry: StandardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(s"hibernate.cfg.${environment.toString}.xml").build
val metadataSources: MetadataSources = new MetadataSources(registry)
val sessionFactory: SessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata.buildSessionFactory
```

Where `Environment` is a language-specific enumeration type.